# I am trying to Logout, I am using AsynStorage package for persistant data, Logout is working but i got a warining. I have no idea to fix this,

Tags: react-native, error-handling, warnings

LOG  Error removing item: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

const login = (userEmail, userPasswd) => {

```
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/account/login`,
            { userEmail, userPasswd }
        ).then(res => {

            let userInfo = res.data;
            // console.log("Checkdata...", userInfo)    
            // if(res.status ==200) {
            setUserInfo(userInfo)
            AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo))
            setLoading(false)
            // }                 

        }).catch(e => {
            if (userEmail !== userEmail && userPasswd !== userPasswd) {
                setError(`login error ${e.res}`);
                setLoading(false)
                Toast.show('Email or Password not match.');
            }

        })

    } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false)
        console.error(error)
        Toast.show('Email or Password not match.');
    }


}
const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
        setUserInfo({})
        useNavigate('Login')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error removing item: ${error}`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try after commenting  useNavigate('Login') line
in logout function

Comment: You mean  like this                                                                                             useNavigate('/Login')

Comment: I found the solution after removing useNavigate('Login') line , THank you for your Suggest

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Answer (score 0):

the way u called useNavigate cannot be used it can be used like this

```
const navigation = useNavigate()
```

and then

```
const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
        setUserInfo({})
       navigation.navigate('Login')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error removing item: ${error}`);
    }
};
```